# How to Zoom Map Pin Area Using zoomRect in MKMapview And Disable Current Location Click Event?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I made one demo for zooming all pins which are placed on map.

1) I have used **zoomRect** for zooming all pins for visibility but it is not showing properly.

2)My Second Question is I got my current location as well as all pins,When I click on pin it gives me all details regarding that pin,
But When I click on current location pin It has been **crashed**  give me solution ,I do not want to click on my current location pin 
How can I disable and remove click event.

I have used :-

```
if (annotation == mapView.userLocation)
    {
        return nil;
    }
```

but it will only hide pin not disable pin.

## my code is

```
MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;
        for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapViewMap.annotations)
        {
            MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
            MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x , annotationPoint.y ,0.1, 0.1);
            zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
        }
        [self.mapViewMap setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
```

## Image is OutPut

[image]

## Expected Output is like

[image]

Thank you in advance ,I hope you will give me answer for both.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For 1), you could use the built in `showAnnotations:animated:` function [see documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapview/1452309-showannotations?language=objc)
Otherwise, you could try this:

```
func zoomToAllAnnotations() { 
    // Exclude if you don't want to include the user's location
    let annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(mapView.userLocation.coordinate) 
    var zoomRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1) 
    for annotation in mapView.annotations { 
        let annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate) 
        let pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1) 
        zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect) 
    } 
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, animated: true) 
}
```

Regarding 2), you could try `pinView.canShowCallout = false` for your currentLocation annotation. Here's [link to documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkannotationview/1452451-canshowcallout).